# Count the number of instances of a digit in a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, count, digit

If I have a column and the cells are

```
579
39
357
3467
34579
```

I want to be able to count the number of times any of the digits occurs. For example, 3 occurs 4 times in this range.

I tried using the countif function, but this seems to only work if the only thing in the cell is a 3.

Is this possible using a function, or will I have to do a workaround?

Comment: Try a loop with `instr` and increment counter each time `instr` > 0

Comment: What `Countif()` function did you try? I doubt that it won't work for what you want to get.

Comment: I was going to say, there's no way `Countif` won't work...but it appears you are right! I was thinking to use `=Countif(A1:A10,"*3*")` as a test, but you can't use wildcards with numbers. Just learned that.

Comment: Batman, I used `index/match` for the first time today <3

Comment: @findwindow - Today is the first day of the rest of your life. :D

Answer (score 3):

Try using using [Application Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) on a native [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616).

```
application.evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2:A99)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A99, 3, """")))")
```

This will count multiple occurrences within a single value; e.g. `233453` hold **3** occurrences of **3**.

If I was doing this, I would qualify the parent worksheet in those cell range addresses to avoid any confusion. The **external** parameter of the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) can help you construct a string to be evaluated as a formula.

Comment: literally 2 seconds away from posting this. :P

Comment: I was three seconds and a quarter. I was trying to get `Countif()` to work - which it doesn't :/

Comment: How about bulk loading a variant array and cycling through the array with `Len` and `Replace` ?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around `evaluate` ;_;

Comment: @findwindow - You type or concatenate a string together that looks like a formula on a worksheet. It can have the `=` or not; doesn't matter. Throw that into [Application.Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) and it returns the result just as if you put it on a worksheet.

Comment: Hmm yea I think it's the string part that gets me. Haven't played with it for a while, forget why I cried last time I tried it XD

Comment: This is a pretty neat formula.  I (coincidentally) am working on a spreadsheet now where this works wonderfully! Thanks Jeeped, as always.